# Random int function

Tags: java

Can someone explain why `(int) (Math.random()*12-3)` returns values between -2 and 8 while `(int) (Math.random()*12)-3` returns between -3 and 8?

The difference is the placement of a parenthesis, but I don't know the "under the hood" reason why it makes a difference. If the lowest value that `Math.random()` can return is 0, that 0*12 = 0 and both should end up with -3 as a minimum.
I assume it has to do with casting to an int and 0.x to 1.  Is it just that it is (theoretically) impossible to hit 0.00000000...?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you just happened to not see a -3 while you were running the first calculation? Try 
Putting the `Math.random()` into a `double`, and doing both calculations, printing the to sysout. They should, in theory, be returning the same number.

Comment: This is a good question. The answers below hopefully illustrate the effects of casting to an `int` at different times in the calculation.  Note that `Math.random()` can return 0, but not 1.

Comment: I tested it by running a while loop that would only stop when -3 was hit.  It ran for about an hour without stopping.  
I teach AP CSA and am asking/testing this because the question showed up on a study guide and it made the claim that -2 was the min for the first function.  When I tested the second function it generated -3 pretty quickly.

Comment: It’s entirely possible to run it for hours and hours and not generate a 0 - but it still can. The other one did much quicker since generating a random value less han 1/12 is much more likely than one exactly equal to 0

Answer (score 3):

The first one can return `-3`, it is just very unlikely.

[`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()):

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

So when you have `(int) (Math.random()*12-3)`, inside the inner parentheses, the result will be a double, which you cast to an `int`. This truncates the decimal places, so unless `Math.random() * 12` returns *exactly* 0 (And then once you subtract 3 to get exactly -3), `Math.random() * 12 -3`, will return at the lowest `2.{...}`, and it will get truncated to -2.

When you do:

```
(int) (Math.random()*12)-3
```

The casting is of greater [precedence](http://java.operator-precedence.com/) than the subtraction, so it is greater likelihood to get truncated to `0`. Then you subtract three, which results in `-3`.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to order of operations along with the fact that `(int) someNumber` **truncates** `someNumber` if it is a `double`. This means that in the first case, it is exceedingly improbable (but possible) that `Math.random()` returns zero, **in which case** the expression would evaluate to -3. However, any other small value produces `(int) -2.[...]` which becomes -2 because it is truncated (the decimals are simply cut off).

In the other case, `(int)` is applied to `Math.random()*12`, then 3 is subtracted from the result. Here, any time `Math.random()*12 < 1` you get `0 - 3 = -3` as the result. This happens about `1/12` of the time, thus you see it producing -3 quite often.

Answer (score 0):

Casting to int with (int) truncates the floating point value towards 0. So with `(int) (Math.random()*12-3)`, even if we get -2.9999, `(int) -2.9999` = -2. Whereas if we calculate `(int) (Math.random()*12)`, we can truncate, for example, 0.5 to 0, and then 0-3 = -3.

Answer (score 0):

They both can reach -3.

`Math.random()` returns a `double` between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive)

Casting to `int` truncates the value closer to 0: `(int)(-2.9) == -2`, and `(int)(2.9) == 2`.  Effectively, it makes negative numbers "bigger" and positive numbers "smaller".

The difference is `(int) (Math.random()*12)-3` evaluates only the `Math.random()*12` part and then casts to `int` - any random value less than 1/12 will result in a result of 0 when cast to an int, then subtracting 3 leaves -3.

The original case can result in -3, but ONLY when `Math.random()` provides a result of 0 - much more rare than providing a value less than 1/12.